# python check if colour exists on mouse click

Tags: python, colors, coordinates

I am trying to automate part of a game. I've done all but one part of what I need and its proving to be difficult. My code so far:

```
import win32api, win32con, time
import win32com.client as comclt

counter = 0
holder = 611

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

click(100,470)#click auto
time.sleep(1)
click(336,222)#click private parking
time.sleep(0.5)
click(1200,330)#click steal
time.sleep(1)
click(429,y)#select car
```

The last line "select car" is where I am having an issue. Basically I cannot always steal a car because the attempt will fail so I need a way to check if a car has been stolen. Once you steal a car it gives you some info in a row and at the end is a colour bar. What I would like to do is this:

After stealing a car, check to see if the colour red exists at x,y coordinates. If so, do something else (which is already done). If not I will set the y coord back. What is the best way for me to go about checking whether the colour red is present?

Answer (score 0):

solved using: color = win32gui.GetPixel(win32gui.GetDC(win32gui.GetActiveWindow()), 1242 , 523)